# Text to speech for mobile platforms

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, text-to-speech

I'm looking for a TTS solution for iOS, Android and Windows 8 which works without an internet connection and is also available in German. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

OpenEars is a offline Text To Speech and Speech To Text Library.

You can check it's documentation here:
[openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/)

Some Online libraries:

- [Google TTS](http://weston.ruter.net/2009/12/12/google-tts/)
- [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/index.htm)